# How to make changes in Ms-access remotely

Tags: ms-access-2013

I made access database for inventory to my company and split it to front end and back end now i want to connect more than two remote pc by the same database.

Answer (score 0):

Under the External Data Tab.  The Access Button will allow you to specify the location of the file on the network.  Choose link to the data source.

Comment: Thanks how to find the data source ?

Comment: You choose the "back end" access database you've created.  It'll need to be on some sort of network share.

Comment: Thanks again but The stores far away from each other so i'm using wifi how to make the connection ?

Comment: If you're on the same network, just share the folder the file is in.  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770880(v=ws.11).aspx

Comment: This is really beyond the scope of the question you asked, which I've already answered. I don't know what resources you have available.  Share it on dropbox for a quick and dirty approach.

Comment: Thanks for your help i will post this question next time.

Answer (score 0):

Short of using a server, you can use remote desktop etc., but you would have to have a free computer on the network for each remote user to run the front-end.

Comment: Thanks for replying but i want to know if it possible to put back-end file on server and link it with the front-end file and how to do it ? because i don't want full access to my computer by using remote desktop .